# Customising validation messages in Play Framework 2

Tags: scala, internationalization, validation, playframework-2.0

I am trying to customise the validation messages in Play.

I found the following entry in the file [`$PLAY_HOME/src/main/resources/messages`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages):

```
error.max=Must be less or equal to {0}
```

I redefined the validation message in my file conf/messages:

```
error.max=TEST, Maximal: {0}
```

But I am still getting the default message.  I restarted the play application, but it is still not working.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The solution is to define the message in the specific (language dependant) message files.
When I add this line to my file conf/messages.de:

```
error.max=TEST GERMAN, Maximal: {0}
```

works like a charm!  Otherwise the entry in conf/messages is ignored (as above mentioned).  Very counterintuitive, I would say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem (although I was using a different language), maybe it works for you as well.

I had to put the following in my controller (otherwise it will be determined on the language that the browser requests).

```
implicit val defaultLang = Lang.availables.headOption.getOrElse(Lang.defaultLang)
```

And in my view I had to add an extra implicit argument for the language:

```
@(title:String)(implicit lang:play.api.i18n.Lang)
```

I am not sure what language your browser requests, but that may cause it to revert to the default messages. The above construct makes sure it uses the available languages as defined in the configuration. I am not sure, but it might require you to rename your messages file to something like `messages.en-US` (depending on your configuration).

Comment: Thank you, it works!  This is really confusing, either a bug or poor documentation.  I am going to update the anwer